# Apache2 server configured in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I configure the Apache server in ubuntu where DicrectoryRoot is /srv/proxy but when I call the webpage in browser it downloaded the page. Basically directory has /srv/proxy/proxy.pac, I want to see the proxy.pac file in the browser instead of download.

index.html files shows properly in the browser but if I put proxy.pac instead of index.html file then the files has download. I want the browser will show the content of proxy.pac.

Any thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers downloaded files based on two headers:

1. Content-Type
2. Content-Disposiiton.

You can see the header by using below command:

curl -s -D - "http://your.domain.com" | head -n 20

To prevent downloading file by the browser we need to set Content-Type text/plain .filetypes (.pac, .doc) in the default000.conf that will display the content in the browser.